# Launching a a bash script through bash myscript.sh vs ./myscript.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There are two ways of executing a bash script from a Linux CLI.

Either you do:

```
bash myscript.sh
```

or:

```
./myscript.sh
```

At first I thought both methods were identical. However I've noticed at my work that `sudo bash` is disabled by system administration (ie I need root permission to do that) while `sudo ./` is no problem.

What is the difference between launching a script through `bash myscript.sh` vs `./myscript.sh`? And is there a logical explanation for not allowing the user to execute a script through `sudo bash myscript.sh` while allowing him to do `./myscript.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This addresses how the kernel finds and executes the command you just typed.

When you have a file in the current directory and you execute it with

```
./file
```

the kernel examines the permissions of the file, and then examines the first line of the file, and if it finds a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), it simply uses that.  A proper Bash script should have `#!/bin/bash` or possibly `#!/usr/bin/env bash` where the path to the binary can be different on different systems (maybe you have Bash in `/usr/bin/bash` or `/usr/local/bin/bash` on your system).

(If the file does not have [executable permission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) for you, you simply get an error, and the contents of the file are ignored.)

If the file is in a directory on the `PATH`, you don't need to specify its path (which in the previous case was a relative path -- `./` means "in the current directory"), and it doesn't need to be in the current directory.

```
bash
```

finds a binary named `bash` from somewhere on your `PATH` (probably somewhere like `/bin/bash`) and executes that.  In the absence of a shebang line, the file is examined for a [magic marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number), which in this case is an ELF binary magic marker, and so the routine to execute that kind of file is invoked.  As a final fallback, the file is passed to the user's default shell, as described below.

Finally,

```
bash ./file
```

or

```
bash file
```

launches `bash` and gives it the `file` as its first argument.  (In the latter case, `file` can be a file on your `PATH`, too.)  This can have two outcomes;

- The file contains a valid Bash script, and it is executed.
- The file contains something else, but it is interpreted as Bash commands anyway.

There is also

```
sh file
```

which is correct only if the file contains `sh` commands, which is a subset of the commands allowed by `bash`.  It is a fairly common error to execute Bash scripts with `sh` (whereas executing proper `sh` files with `bash` is fine, albeit somewhat wasteful, because Bash is backwards-compatible with `sh`).

Regarding `sudo`, it doesn't really make sense to allow `sudo ./script` because the user could simply create a script which contains `bash -i` to gain root privileges.  Perhaps disallowing `sudo bash` is just meant as a gentle nudge to remind privileged users to not be overtly sloppy with their privileges (but if they don't understand the nudge, it's clearly not serving the intended purpose; and obviously, the security of the system will already be extremely questionable).

Comment: I tried my darndest to find a duplicate, but couldn't find one.  There are many near-duplicates, but I couldn't find a previous question about precisely this topic.  I'm hoping somebody else is able to find an correctly mark a duplicate, but in the meantime, here's my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
bash myscript.sh
```

This runs `bash` (which must be in a directory that is part of your `PATH`) in a new process and instructs it (assuming that `bash` refers to the Bash shell) to load and execute `myscript.sh` (which must be in a directory that is part of your `PATH` or in that process' current working directory). Note that it is always `bash` that will be used to interpret the content of `myscript.sh` in this case.

```
./myscript.sh
```

This runs `./myscript.sh`. In the course of this, the file is checked for a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line. The script is executed in a new process using the shell specified in that line, or using a default shell (as specified in the `SHELL` environment variable or `/etc/passwd`). Therefore the actual program interpreting `myscript.sh` may vary in this case.

Comment: Ack borrowing -- I incorporated into my answer the notes about `myscript.sh` anywhere on the `PATH` and the fallback to a default shell, which I had originally overlooked.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad this was useful.

Comment: @John Kugelman, thanks for your edit. I have added more detail to the path part of your changes and rolled back the "system call" part because I disagree on that... could you explain why you consider that part wrong or inaccurate?

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for pointing that out. My chain of thought here was that using the second command, the `exec*` system call will trigger shebang/magic checking in the kernel. I more or less wanted to mention that without adding too much detail. After that, I decided to add the system call to the first option too to prevent readers from thinking that that case may be handled fundamentally different. I have a meeting now, but I'll consider rephrasing later.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `./hello.bash` in your current shell  and  type enter, this happen in the system

```
strace -ff -p 4768 #PID OF MY MAIN SHELL
Process 4768 attached
read(0, ".", 1)                         = 1
write(2, ".", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "/", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "/", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "h", 1)                         = 1


write(2, "h", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "e", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "e", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\t", 1)                        = 1

stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/tux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/tux/programming", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/tux/programming/bash", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/tux/programming/bash/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

getdents(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768)     = 128 

geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
getuid()                                = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
access("./hello.bash", X_OK)            = 0
stat("./hello.bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=32, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
getuid()                                = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
access("./hello.bash", R_OK)            = 0
clone(Process 4998 attached
[pid  4998] execve("./hello.bash", ["./hello.bash"], [/* 55 vars */]) = 0
```

From what i think, the shell check if file exist using stat system call and the execution permission and read permission, after that you can see a new process begin create with clone syscall and after that the script begin executed in the new process, i think everything happen in user space, the only thing the kernel does is the system call and load the proccess image in memory with the help of the linker

Answer (score -2):

Executing Bash scripts with ./script.sh is the only method when the PATH variable doesn't contain the Path to the directory. If it did, it could be executed via script.sh as well.